# HW beeping in Windows

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have a very strange problem. I've bought a new laptop - `Asus G73JH with Windows 7 x64 Ulti.`
Everything worked fine until I've installed so many apps that the system collapsed and I was forced to revert to an earlier restore point. I had to reinstall some drivers too.

Now, when the system is running, I'm hearing a **very tiny silent beeping coming from the notebook case**.

But it happens **ONLY when the OS is running**.
It's definitely not the POST, nor a speaker. It is a constant beeping lasting from 3 to 30 seconds.. and happens randomly very oft, in most cases when the notebook runs on battery.

Do you have any idea what it should be?

Could it be the coolers? that it runs on some resonance frequency or something..
Or could it be a sound card driver? or maybe a catalyst driver?

Comment: Note that this laptop has a speaker under, supposed to act as a subwoofer. And it tends to have [some issues](http://superuser.com/questions/163868/crackling-sound-on-windows-sounds-on-an-asus-g73jh), so it could come from this. At least you have a tiny beeping. I had an awfully loud noise.

Comment: Just to rule something out, please run `net stop beep` on the command line. This will stop the service which is providing the beep through the internal speaker (if any). If it went away with that, it's the OS which tries to tell you something.

Comment: @Bobby: wow, I didn't know this "beep" service running. thanks for the information!

Comment: What drivers did you reinstall?

Comment: I reinstalled the BDRom driver( although it didn't help and I still cannot burn anything)

Answer (score 0):

Is your network connection over WLAN? My laptop (although it's a Dell Latitude D830) does the same if running on battery AND using WLAN. Strange, but that seems to happen regardless of the OS (tried Windows 7, various Linux distributions and PC-BSD 8).

Comment: Yep.. WLAN and when using a wireless USB modem too !

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search turned up [another user with the same problem](http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus-gaming-notebook-forum/509344-g73jh-beeping-when-idle.html). They're inclined to believe it's the GPU. If I were to venture a guess I would say something like Motherboard Monitor warning of heat (threshold set too low in BIOS or something).